# Sharing pdb files amongst developers so everyone can step into code

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dll

If I build a project (lets call it Project X) on my computer and copy its dll and pdb files into another solution (Project Y), whilst I am debugging Project Y I can easily step back into the original code files of Project X. I guess the pdb file contains the full path on my computer.

Other developers also work on both Project X and Project Y and it would be nice if they could also step into the actual files on their computer whilst debugging. The problem is that their directory structure may be different to my directory structure, so the path references embedded in the pdb file won't work.

So what is the easiest way to allow all developers to step into another solution's files on their machine whilst debugging, assuming they have copies of a dll and pdb file built on someone else's computer?

Answer (score 2):

[StackHash.com](http://www.stackhash.com/) has some relevant blog posts about setting up [symbol](http://www.stackhash.com/blog/post/Setting-up-a-Symbol-Server.aspx) and [source](http://www.stackhash.com/blog/post/Setting-up-a-Source-Server.aspx) servers.  That might be overkill for what you are looking for.  But for public releases, where multiple developers may need to look at customer or [WER](https://winqual.microsoft.com/member/wer) generated minidumps, setting up a symbol server looks to be ideal.  Also, see their [Getting Started with WinQual](http://www.stackhash.com/WinQual/) series which covers some of the same topics.

One of the issues you'll run into is whether your co-workers even have the same version of the source files that were used in your build.  The source indexing described in the previous links works with your source control to automatically get the appropriate versions when the pdb is loaded.